# Intervention Image NotReadableException when using base64 image data

Tags: php, laravel, intervention

I’m using Intervention Image in a Laravel project and I’m trying to create an image from a base64 encoded string.

Here is the code of the Service:

```
<?php
namespace App\Services;
use DB;
use Image;
class Compressor
{
    public function compress()
    {
           $files = DB::table('app_payment_reports')
        ->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('voucher_file_type', '=', 'image/jpeg')
                ->orWhere('voucher_file_type', '=', 'image/png');
        })
            ->whereNull('new_voucher_file_size')
            ->get();


        
        foreach ($files as $file) {

      
          $imageData = $file->voucher_file_base64;
          
          $image = Image::make($file->voucher_file_base64);

            
            
            $originalSize = strlen($file->voucher_file_base64);
            $compressedImage = $image->encode('jpg', 75);
            $newSize = strlen($compressedImage);
            DB::table('app_payment_reports')
                ->where('id', $file->id)
                ->update([
                    'new_voucher_file_size' => $newSize,
                    'voucher_file_base64' => $newBase64
                ]);
        }
    }

    public function getTotalImages()
    { return DB::table('app_payment_reports')
        ->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('voucher_file_type', '=', 'image/jpeg')
                  ->orWhere('voucher_file_type', '=', 'image/png');
        })
            ->whereNull('new_voucher_file_size')
            ->count();
    }
}
```

However, when I run this code, I get the following error:

```
  Intervention\Image\Exception\NotReadableException 

  Image source not readable

  at vendor/intervention/image/src/Intervention/Image/AbstractDecoder.php:351
    347▕             case $this->isBase64():
    348▕                 return $this->initFromBinary(base64_decode($this->data));
    349▕ 
    350▕             default:
  ➜ 351▕                 throw new NotReadableException("Image source not readable");
    352▕         }
    353▕     }
    354▕ 
    355▕     /**

      +3 vendor frames 

  4   app/Services/Compressor.php:25
      Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic()

  5   app/Console/Commands/TestCommand.php:23
      App\Services\Compressor::compress()
```

According to the Intervention Image documentation, it should be possible to use base64 encoded image data with the make method. However, it doesn’t seem to be working in my case.

Here’s an example of how the data is stored in the voucher_file_base64 column:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAASABIAAD/4QBYRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgAAgESAAMAAAABAAEAAIdpAAQAAAABAAAAJgAAAAAAA6ABAAMAAAABAAEAAKACAAQAAAABAAAE2qADAAQAAAABAAAEmQAAAAD...
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this issue and how to fix it?

Comment: Always try to dd() the information before you send it to Image::make or anything. In this case, according do the exception, what you're sending to Image::make isn't valid base64, so fix that first. This part: `data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/` is too much, how did you receive that part?

Comment: are you the base64 data is valid?